# How can I generate web-safe JSON from a Mongo database?

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB and MapReduce to process large amounts of data and identify unique documents.  When I use mongodump or the REST interface, the result documents look something like:

```
  ....
},
{
    "_id": 35696,
    "value": {
        "row": {
            "A": "AAA",
            undefined,
            "C": "CCC",
            "D": "DDD",
            "E": "EEE",
            "F": "FFF",
            "G": "GGG",
            "H": "HHH",
            "I": "III",
            "J": "JJJ",
            "K": "KKK",
            "L": "LLL",
            "M": "MMM",
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            undefined,
            "Y": "YYY",
            "Z": "ZZZ"
        },
        "count": 1
    }
},
{
  ....
```

Note how there are `undefined` fields.  I expected fields that do not exist in all documents to be ignored.  When I try to use this data in the web application I'm developing, Chrome throws an exception.  [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) also rejects the format.  How can I have Mongo produce JSON that is immediately consumable by web technologies?  I'd prefer not to post-process the data, although I will if I must.

Comment: how about some defensive coding on the server to prevent the flawed data from being inserted to the JSON DTO altogether?

Comment: The data is not flawed. The input data is more like a sparse array, where each key-value is not required.

Comment: @WilliBallenthin then why not put some other value on the placeholder? something which keeps the JSON format valid like "-1" : "X" ?

Comment: Do you mean something like s/undefined,/"-1": "X"/g ? Yes, this is what I'm doing in the mean time (actually, removing the undefined fields), but I was hoping this would be doable from within Mongo.

Comment: Hi Willi. Can you give me a little more information as to where these "undefined" values are coming from? How are these being inserted into the document? What process is leading to their creation? How are you specifying these documents?

Comment: @brandon10gen I insert documents into the database that have varied schemas. For example, there may be a document {"A": "AAA", "B": "BBB"} and a document {"A": "AAA", "C": "CCC"} .  When I dump the database, the first document looks like {"A": "AAA", "B": "BBB", undefined}, and the second looks like {"A": "AAA", undefined, "C": "CCC"}.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @WilliBallenthin what language are you using to insert this data?

Comment: @WilliBallenthin how does MapReduce fit into the picture? Are you doing anything that might mess with the values in the documents? More directly: can you recreate this problem simply by saving the documents as described (via pymongo) and then dumping with mongodump? I'm having trouble reproducing that locally.